# Same Javascript function doesn't work in other project

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm making a Chrome extension for my own use. This code works perfectly when used in other projects. I need to paste something to my clipboard using the following function:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('buttonOne')
btn.addEventListener('click', klik)

function klik() {
    copyTextToClipboard('hey!')
}

function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
    alert('im being called')
    var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
    copyFrom.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
    copyFrom.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    copyFrom.blur();
    document.body.removeChild(copyFrom);
}
```

I make sure the function gets executed by putting the first line `alert('im being called')`

What can be the reason this function doesn't paste anything to the clipboard?

Comment: Well for one thing I'd be setting `copyFrom.value`, not `.textContent`.

Comment: yes i did. but the weird thing is that it work in other files but not this one they all have the same structure.

Comment: That's weird. I'm going to update VS code maybe it's a bug. Thanks!

Comment: @Yogi I even tried it in a VM but still the function doesn't work. Which code editor do you use?